# How to replace all lines except one word per line using a regular expression

Tags: regex

**How do you replace all lines except one word per line using a regular expression?**

I tried the following regex that mostly works but all the lines after the last match remain.

Find what: `(?s)(.*?property": ")(\w+)(.*?$)`

Replace with: `\2\n`

**Simplified text file:**

```
random lines of text
{
    "property": "my1Value",
    "property": "my2Value",
    "property": "my3Value",
}
more random lines of text
```

**Expecting one word per line:**

```
my1Value
my2Value
my3Value
```

Comment: What regex tool are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just match single characters when the main pattern doesn't match. These will then get replaced by the empty string (since the capture groups captured nothing):

Find: `(?s)"property": "([^"]+)".*?(\R)|.`

Replace: `\1\2`

Comment: Neat! It does remove all other lines, but the 7 lines become 69 lines with lots of line feeds. I think it must replace every single match with a line feed?

I like the regex you suggested :)  This was useful to help me understand it http://xenon.stanford.edu/~xusch/regexp/

Comment: Ah yes, I updated it to not generate a newline in the replacement string, but only take the one that exists in the input  (`\R`)